# Jquery Each not outputting all data on page

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, rss, youtube

I have this code which works at retrieving data from You Tube. I can see this by the alert message. The problem is in IE8 and below, it doesn't output the list of 3 items to the page. It only outputs the last image.

You can view the code [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zegnm/)

Any help much appreciated.

```
$.each(data.feed.entry.slice(1, 4), function(i, item) {
                        //if(i == 3) return false;
                        var title = item.title.$t;
                        var url = item.link[0].href;
                        var thumbUrl = item.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
                        thumbs_data += '<li><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ title +'"><img alt="'+ title+'" src="'+thumbUrl+'"</a></li>';
                        alert(thumbs_data);
                    });
```

Comment: It is unlikely we can help without seeing exactly what `data.feed.entry` is and whether there are any script errors generated in IE8.

Comment: Apologies. Here is the code...http://jsfiddle.net/zegnm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code in IE8, one possible problem may be that `item.title.$t` has quotation marks in it which I think may be messing up your generated HTML.  You could try remove the quote marks by changing this:

```
var title = item.title.$t;
```

to this:

```
var title = item.title.$t.replace(/"/g, "");
```

And, the other problem I found is that you are missing a closing brace on the img tag in your generated HTML.

---

Change the thumbs_data line to this to add the closing > for the img tag:

```
thumbs_data += '<li><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ title +'"><img alt="'+ title+'" src="'+thumbUrl+'"></a></li>';
```

Once you fix those, you can see this jsFiddle work in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7L2Ws/

Note: I found this problem by outputting the generated HTML you were adding to `thumbs_data` to `console.log()` each time through the loop so I could look at the HTML to see where the problems were.

Comment: You can also just switch `'` for `"`: `thumbs_data += "<li><a href='"+ url +"' title='"+ title +"'><img alt='"+ title+"' src='"+thumbUrl+"'</a></li>";` That will also work as now all the `"` characters are always between `'` characters instead.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Yeah, I thought of that, but I don't think the OP really wants the quote characters in the title anyway.

Comment: Completely forgot, +1 for nice debugging and provided solution and fiddle, well done.

Comment: It was as simple as the missing closing tag as you said @jfriend00 Thanks everyone, it is now working. Thanks also for the insight into the quotation marks!